# How to retrieve mongodb data from server (node.js) to my AngularJS Route

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, angular-ui-router

This is my `Server.js` file (NodeJS):

```
var express = require('express');
var server= require('http');
var path= require("path");
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var app= express();

var staticDIR = path.resolve(__dirname, "./www");``
app.use(express.static(staticDIR));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.get("*", function (req, res) {
    var indexViewPath = path.resolve(__dirname, "./www/index.html");
    res.sendFile(indexViewPath);
});
var dbURI = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/mydatabase';
mongoose.connect(dbURI);
mongoose.connection.on('connected', function () {
    console.log('Mongoose connected to ' + dbURI);
});
mongoose.connection.on('error',function (err) {
    console.log('Mongoose connection error: ' + err);
});
mongoose.connection.on('disconnected', function () {
    console.log('Mongoose disconnected');
});
process.on('SIGINT', function() {
    mongoose.connection.close(function () {
        console.log('Mongoose disconnected through app termination');
        process.exit(0);
    });
});

var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    password:String,
    email: {type: String, unique:true},
    createdOn: { type: Date, default: Date.now }
    //modifiedOn: Date,
    //lastLogin: Date
});

mongoose.model( 'User', userSchema );
var User = mongoose.model('User');

var CompanySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    CompanyName: String,
    password:String,
    email: {type: String, unique:true},
    createdOn: { type: Date, default: Date.now }
    //modifiedOn: Date,
    //lastLogin: Date
});
mongoose.model( 'company', userSchema );
var company = mongoose.model('company');

User.find({}, function(err, users) {
    if(!err){
        console.log(users);
    }
});

company.find({}, function(err, users) {
    if(!err){
        console.log(users);
    }
});

app.post('/account', function(req, res){
    new company({
        CompanyName:req.body.Company,
        email:req.body.email,
        password:req.body.password
    }).save(function(err,doc){
            if(err)res.json(err);
            else res.send("succesfully inserted");
            console.log(res);

        });
});
```

This is my Middleware to get tha data:

```
app.get('/details', function (req, res) {
    console.log('I received a GET request');
    company.find({}, function(err, users) {
        if(!err){
            console.log(users);
        }
        else{
            res.render('/details',{users:docs})
        }
    });

});


app.listen(9000);
console.log("Server Running on port 3000");
```

This is my Controller.js (AngularJS) file:

```
   angular.module('myApp', ['ngMaterial','firebase','ui.router'])
        .controller('detailsCtrl', function($scope,myfirebaseAddress,$location,$timeout) {
            var ref = new Firebase(myfirebaseAddress);

        })
```

This is my route where I want to show the mongoDb saved data

```
 <ui-view>
        <div class="sub-header">
            <h3>Company Details</h3>
        </div>

    <ul>
       <li ng-repeat="users in user">
           {{user.email}}
       </li>
    </ul>
    </ui-view>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Controller to get the requested data

```
.controller('detailsCtrl', function($scope,$http) {

    $scope.users = [];

    $http.get('/details').then(function(d)
        {
            console.log(d);
            $scope.users= d.data;
        },function(err)
        {
            console.log(err);            }
    )

})
```

server route

```
app.get('/details', function (req, res) {
    console.log('I received a GET request');
    company.find({}, function(err, users) {
        if(!err){
           res.json(users);
        }

    });

});
```

Answer (score 2):

instead if writing below code

```
if(!err){
        console.log(users);
    }
    else{
        res.render('/details',{users:docs})
    }
```

do like this

```
if(!err){
            res.send(users);
        }
        else{
            res.send('could not retrived data');
        }
```

in controller side you can get your all data inside success call back function.here also check

```
app.listen(9000);
console.log("Server Running on port 3000");
```

this should like below.

```
app.listen(9000);
console.log("Server Running on port 9000");
```

Comment: on "/details"  route haven't receive any response

Comment: because there is nou object like `docs`..its `users`.check your code again.

Comment: i figured out the problem that i'm using app.get  Two times in server.js one  for 'app.get('*')'  static path and one for getting data but when i remove 'app.get(*)'  which is place with static path then i receive the mongodb data on console

Answer (score 0):

If you want to retrieve your data, you must stop this:

res.render('/details',{users:docs})

If you want to serve data with an angular app, you have to stop to render a view and start to give back a json in your response.

```js
res.jsonp(users)
```

Then you've to adjust your controller.
Write a service like:

```
angular.module('yourApp')
.service('userService', function($http){
    return {
        getUsers: function(url) {
            return $http.get(url)
            }
        }
    })
```

this should return an http promise.
In your controller you handle this promise this way:

```
$scope.users = function(){
        userService.getUsers('/users')
            .then(function(users){
                //You have your users object
            })
    }
```

remember to handle the unsuccesfull case of your promise

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the angular http module to get the node/express response that get the data from mongodb in client side; like this: https://github.com/J-Alex/api_rest_mvc

Comment: That link may answer the question, but please post the relevant code snippets from that link in the answer. This is because even when the link is removed, StackOverflow users will still have access to the answer.